# How to deal with abstract classes as entry api contracts for microservices and tackle polymorphism same time?

Tags: java, spring, polymorphism, microservices

I am going through dozen tutorials which prove to me of very little help because production code is not an animal, bird or human. Not a weapon of type cutting or shooting it is much more complex to reason about.

So returning to reality, scenario:
**service 1** is exchanging messages with **service 2** through Kafka, messages are serialized/deserialized with Jackson, the model class is shared between services as jar.

Now the plague part, the culmination of evil :

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = Id.NAME,
        property = "type",
        visible = true
    )
    @JsonSubTypes({@Type(
        value = InternalTextContent.class,
        name = "text"
    ), @Type(
        value = InternalImageContent.class,
        name = "image"
    ), @Type(
        value = InternalAudioContent.class,
        name = "audio"
    ), @Type(
        value = InternalCustomContent.class,
        name = "custom"
    )})
    public abstract class InternalContent {
        @JsonIgnore
        private ContentType type;

        public InternalContent() {
        }
```

Obviously when the time will come to work with this content we will have something like:

```
message.getInternalContent
```

which results to a sea of `switch` statements, `if` conditions, `instanceof` and wait for it ... downcasting everywhere

And this is just one property example the wrapping object contains. Clearly I cannot add polymorphic behaviour to InternalContent , because hellooo it is within a jar.

What went wrong here? Is it even wrong?
How do I add polymorphic behaviour ? To add a new mitigating layer, I still need `instanceof` in some factory to create a new type of polymorphic objects family which are editable to add the desired behavior? Not even sure it is going to be better, it just smells and make me want to shoot the advocates which throw blind statement like `instanceof` with downcasting is a code smell" torturing people like me who genuinely care, which makes me wonder if they ever worked on a real project. I deliberately added system environment details to understand how to model not just the code but interaction between systems. What are possible redesign options to achieve the "by book" solution?

So far I can think of that sharing domain model is a sin. But then if I use different self-service-contained classes to represent same things for serialization/deserialization I gather flexibility but lose contract and increase unpredictability. Which is what technically happens with HTTP contracts.

Should I send different types of messages with different structures along the wire instead of trying to fit common parts and subtypes for uncommon in a single message type?

To throw more sand at OO , I consider Pivotal the best among the best yet:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java

```
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class
                .isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }
```

AuhenticationManager has a list of AuthenticationProviders like this and selects correct one based on the method above. Does this violate polymorphism ? Sometimes it all just feels as a hype...

Comment: Google for the visitor pattern. That's the way you can use polymorphism, avoid instanceof, and still have the polymorphically called code outside of the shared classes.

Comment: @JBNizet could you please provide example as an answer, because the fact that I can't change the classes  is making it confusing, I will provide more info if you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the visitor pattern.

Example (I'll limit to two subclasses, but you should get the idea):

```
interface InternalContentVisitor<T> {
    T visitText(InternalTextContent c);
    T visitImage(InternalImageContent c);
}

public abstract class InternalContent {
    public abstract <T> T accept(InternalContentVisitor<T> visitor);
    // ...
}

public class InternalTextContent {
    @Override
    public <T> T accept(InternalContentVisitor<T> visitor) {
        return visitor.visitText(this);
    }
}

public class InternalImageContent {
    @Override
    public <T> T accept(InternalContentVisitor<T> visitor) {
        return visitor.visitImage(this);
    }
}
```

This code is completely generic, and can be shared by any application using the classes.

So now, if you want to polymorphically do something in project1 with an InternalContent, all you need to do is to create a visitor. This visitor is out of the InternalContent classes, and can thus contain code that is specific to project1. Suppose for example that project1 has a class Copier that can be used to create a Copy of a text or of an image, you can use

```
InternalContent content = ...; // you don't know the actual type 
Copier copier = new Copier();
Copy copy = content.accept(new InternalContentVisitor<Copy>() {
    @Override
    public Copy visitText(InternalTextContent c) {
        return copier.copyText(c.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public Copy visitImage(InternalImageContent c) {
        return copier.copyImage(c.getImage());
    }
});
```

So, as you can see, there is no need for a switch case. Everything is still done in a polymorphic way, even though the InternalContent class and its subclasses have no dependency at all on the Copier class that only exists in project1.

And if a new `InternalSoundContent` class appears, all you have to do is to add a `visitSound()` method in the visitor interface, and implement it in all the implementations of this interface.

Comment: the only problem is that internalContent is within jar and doesn't have "accept" method, I managed to solve it like :
public class SomeTextContent extends InternalTextContent implements Content {
    @Override
    public void accept(ContentVisitor contentVisitor) {
        contentVisitor.visit(this);
    }
}

Comment: You'll need to modify the shared classes, but as you see, the modification is small and generic, without any coupling to anything in project1 or project2. Otherwise, you'll need adapter classes.

Comment: and that would mean casting? :-)

Comment: If you have absolutly no way to modify the shared classes, I don't think you can do what you want without any casting. But you can limit it to one place, which would return an Adapter class that you can modify the way you want, and thus use polymorphism on that.

Comment: I see, I've modified the class instead, was wondering if there is silver bullet in the end :-) Thank you very much for your time.